# Custom equality of types with statically resolved type parameters

Tags: generics, types, f#, inline, equality

How to implement custom equality methods in F# types with statically resolved type parameters?

I've tried doing it this way:

```
[<CustomEqualityAttribute>]
type Fraction< ^a when ^a: equality and ^a : (static member (*): ^a * ^a -> ^a) > (nominator: ^a, denominator: ^a) =
    member inline this.Nominator = nominator
    member inline this.Denominator = denominator

    member inline this.IsEqualTo(other: Fraction< ^a >) = this.Nominator * other.Denominator = other.Nominator * this.Denominator

    override inline this.Equals(other: obj) =
        match obj with
        | :? Fraction< ^a > as f -> this.IsEqualTo(f)
        | _ -> false
```

I get the following error on the `this.Equals` line:

> This member, function or value declaration may not be declared 'inline'

Why is that? Is it because the `Equals` is an override? If that's the case, is there any way at all to implement the custom equality or am I forced to use an `IEqualityComparer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is that? Is it because the `Equals` is an override?

Yes, it is. An `inline` method of a class is not an *actual* method of the class. Rather, every call to that method at somewhere will be interpreted as its implementation (very similar to C++). Since you are overriding the `Equals` method which is an actual method (from the `Object` class), you cannot make it `inline`.

> If that's the case, is there any way at all to implement the custom equality?

You can extract the *concrete multiplication* out of the type, so you won't be forced to use `inline` for the `Equals` method:

```
[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]
type Frac<'T when 'T : equality> = private {
    nominator : 'T
    denominator : 'T
    mult : 'T -> 'T -> 'T
} with
    member x.Nominator = x.nominator
    member x.Denominator = x.denominator
    override x.Equals other =
        match other with
        | :? Frac<'T> as o -> 
            let ( * ) = x.mult in x.nominator * o.denominator = o.nominator * x.denominator
        | _ -> false
    static member inline Create x y = { nominator = x; denominator = y; mult = ( * ) }
// Test
Frac.Create 1 2 = Frac.Create 3 6 // true
Frac.Create 1.0 2.0 = Frac.Create 3.0 7.0 // false
Frac.Create 1 2 = Frac.Create 3.0 6.0 // compile error
```

Comment: Would that need `#nowarn "1125"`? (The instantiation of the generic type 'Frac' is missing and can't be inferred from the arguments or return type of this member. Consider providing a type instantiation when accessing this type, e.g. 'Frac<_>'.)

Comment: Yes, I ignored that warning. Btw, there is also a warning about considering to implement GetHashCode method so the type can be used with hash-related data structures.